# Getting 401 Unauthorized with a valid JWT token

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, jwt

I have built an API to register an user or log an user in. If the user login is sucessfull it returns a JWT token which is an hour valid. I have added `[Authorize]` at the top of the controller I want to get the data from but it keeps returning Unauthorized 401 in Postman even when I added the token to the request. I have tried all solutions people commented on other blogs but nothing worked for me. Could someone help me out or has the same issue?

Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "AuthApi", Version = "v1" });
            });
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            );
            services.AddCors(c =>
                    {
                        c.AddPolicy("def", builder =>
                        {
                            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials();
                        });
                    });


            // For Entity Framework  
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            // For Identity  
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
            {
                // configure identity options
                o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            // Adding Authentication  
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })

            // Adding Jwt Bearer  
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
                };
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "LoginAPI v1");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });

            app.UseCors("def");

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Controller class I want to retrieve data from:

```
namespace auth.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

My Authentication controller for logging an user in:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
        {
            // Finds and returns a user, if any, who has the specified user name.
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);

            // Checks if username was valid to an user and
            // returns a flag indicating whether the given password is valid for the specified user.
            if (user != null && await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
            {
                // Gets a list of role names the specified user belongs to.
                var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                var authClaims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                };

                // Loop through the user roles
                // Add all userRoles as a claim to authClaims 
                foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
                {
                    authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
                }

                // Generates a key to sign in
                var authSigninKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));

                // Create the token
                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                    audience: _configuration["JWT:Audience"],
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                    claims: authClaims,
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigninKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );

                return Ok(new
                {
                    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                    SecurityTokenNoExpirationException = token.ValidTo
                });
            }
            return Unauthorized();
        }
```

Output:
[image]

Appsettings.json:

[image]

Comment: can you share the jwt, and the configured :
 ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],

Comment: I have updated the post is this what you guys meant?

Comment: please add the token as text. I wanted to inspect it on jwt.io

Comment: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiYW50b25pbyIsImp0aSI6IjU2YWNjNWJjLWUwYTgtNGUxZC1hZDQyLThiYTA4MmM0ZmEzZiIsImV4cCI6MTYwMjc3ODY1MCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMSJ9.ilpaHDw4NmfUPLINddswP9Wj4Kdjkx1epR7IBF2k3qc

Comment: you're validating audience (`ValidateAudience = true,`) but the token doesn't contain and `aud`claim. Try  `ValidateAudience = false,` to see if it works and then debug your code to see why the audience wasn't added

Comment: When checking your token you use `Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"]` as valid audience. Yet when creating the token you set audience to `_configuration["JWT:Audience"]`  That should proably be `_configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"]` too (or vice versa)

Comment: @jps Wow thanks it works now! I really appreciate it! So only when a token has an aud claim it needs to be true.

Comment: @derpirscher I just did what you said now I have an extra code after the jwt I first had what does that stand for?

Comment: *So only when a token has an aud claim it needs to be true.* - I would say it the other way around: when the option is set to true, there must be an audience and it needs to be the same as configured.

Comment: @jps Ah yes I see. When I did what derpischer said and I set the ValidateAudience back to true it worked. So I have now an aud in my token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Recap

In my case I was not using any Identity Server Yet I was providing the Host as a ValidIssuer.
It validated the `Authority` for the algo and keys which returned nothing, this caused the system to throw an unhandled exception.
Solved this By Removing `options.Authority` from `JwtBearerOptions` in `AddJwtBearer(options => ...)`.

After that I faced the 401 ERROR, resolved it by removing `options.Audience` from `JwtBearerOptions` in `AddJwtBearer(options => ...)`, Also added `ValidateLifetime` to `TokenValidationParameters` (which you can see below in part 1)

---

### Code

PART (1) JWT Configuration

in .NET 6 :

```
builder.services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options => 
 {
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() 
    {
       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = jwtSettings.ValidateIssuerSigningKey,
       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.IssuerSigningKey)),
       ValidateIssuer = jwtSettings.ValidateIssuer,
       ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.ValidIssuer,
       ValidateAudience = jwtSettings.ValidateAudience,
       ValidAudience = jwtSettings.ValidAudience,
       RequireExpirationTime = jwtSettings.RequireExpirationTime,
       ValidateLifetime = jwtSettings.RequireExpirationTime,
       ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    };
});
```

---

### Extra

GET your JWT Settings from Appsettings using Either this
Where

> "JsonWebTokenKeys"

is the name of section in `configuration` :

```
var jwtSettings = new JwtSettings();
Configuration.Bind("JsonWebTokenKeys", jwtSettings);
builder.services.AddSingleton(jwtSettings);

//PART (1) => JWT Configuration goes here
//..
//..
```

OR this :

```
services.Configure<JwtSettings>(configuration.GetSection("JsonWebTokenKeys"));
using (ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
{
   var jwtSettings = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<JwtSettings>>().Value;
   
   //PART (1) => JWT Configuration goes here
   //..
   //.. 
}
```